# Narrow generic mapped argument

Tags: typescript, generics, narrowing

Here is code:

```
type T = 'a' | "b"
type M = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

function a(a: 'a') {}
function m1(a: 1) {}

function f<TT extends T>(t: TT, p: M[TT]) {
  switch (t) {
    case "a": {
      a(t)
      m1(p) // Argument of type '1 | 2' is not assignable to parameter of type '1'
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Why `p` wasn't narrowed to `1`? Are there a neat workaround without type casts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to recognize that `p` corrolates with `t` as explained in [microsoft/TypeScript#35873](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35873). You'll need another type guard to narrow `p`. The most straightforward syntax is to use [`switch (true)` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-3.html#switch-true-narrowing) which was recently added in TypeScript 5.3.

```
type T = "a" | "b";
type M = {
  a: 1;
  b: 2;
};

declare function a(a: "a"): void;
declare function m1(a: 1): void

function f<TT extends T>(t: TT, p: M[TT]) {
  switch (true) {
    case t === "a" && p === 1:
      a(t);
      m1(p);
      break;
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBEBDJUA+yBGSDcAUKJFALIJQDeBUUKAXFAIyG3aMBMhAvoQQCYQAxgBsUAJ2gAzAK4A7IcACWAezl0AFA2RoAlIwBuKpf0KDRE6fMWr1AWyZbGTfVCMmCBWQuVqoUgB4YOAgAD2AIOX4AZ1gAPg1gRmCAGigwRlIAbWCAXV0qGihogHclYCEACyhE8RkIAupaWiEUaOhgBHhEVHQAMj70rsQmeiLmzWBdVgmoBw0wafHm7EkUAGsZ7gJtoA)